# Calculate tax before discount

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I have created a rule in Drupal with the following conditions/actions.

[image]

With this rule, I give 10% discount on a specific product type, but the tax (21% in The Netherlands) is still calculated on the old price (without the discount).

For example, without discount I get the following.

- Sub total €28.93
- Tax €6.07
- Total price €35,00

With the discount, I get the following.

- Sub total €25.43
- Tx €6.07
- Total price €31.50

I tried to change the weight of the rule, but it didn't help.

I used the default tax module of Drupal Commerce and all the default settings. Is there something I can do about it?

I tried also the [Commerce Discount](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) module, but with the same behavior.

PS: Prices on this website are shown included of taxes.

After the patch, it is still not working. The Tax should be the following. (The product price is €0.90 with 10% discount; normally the price is €1.00 without the discount.)

- €0.74 (excluded tax)
- €0.16 (tax)
- €0.90 (total)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible, because Drupal Commerce calculate the prices/taxes before the discount. I had the same issue a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems a variation of the issue about [Order discounts are not taken into account during tax calculation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2429595#comment-10952691). Have a look at [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2429595-order-discounts-no-taxes-22.patch) attached to comment nr 22 of that issue.

Without the patch, you get a result similar to [this](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/pre-patch_2.png), while after applying the patch it changes to [this](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/post-patch_2.png).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I applied the patch, but it is still not working. I edit my first post.